# CodeIgniter, Using Redis as session manager

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redis, codeigniter-3

From [github](https://github.com/ericterpstra/ci_sock/tree/master/part_two) the configuration claims that I need to set

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

This is required to store the session data in redis.

However, from [CodeIgniter's guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) If `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` session class will store session data in the DB.

I want to understand, how the database write is bypassed even if we set 'sess_use_database' config to true.

Secondly, the method requires phpredis extension to be installed.

I already have another CI redis library installed from the following [github repository](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis).

Can someone help me to configure the code from ericterpstra, [File Name: ci_sock/part_two/MY_Session.php] so that it can use the above library, instead of phpredis?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, [`phpredis`](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#php-session-handler) is a C extension for PHP, where the [`CI redis`](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis) library is a pure PHP implementation of a redis client. It is probably possible for you to have `phpredis` installed as an extension and still use your `CI redis` library (although you might want to dump it as it is no longer maintained).

If you do install `phpredis` you can bypass the whole CodeIgnitor session configuration issue by just switching the default session handler in your `php.ini` file to use redis.

Here is an example from https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#php-session-handler:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://host1:6379?weight=1, tcp://host2:6379?weight=2&timeout=2.5, tcp://host3:6379?weight=2"
```

This will transparently use your redis storage to store sessions.

Answer (score 1):

**Redis session** is supported in **Codeigniter version 3**

Edit config file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis'; //enable redis session
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://localhost:6379'; // redis hostname:port
```

[Official Documentation Redis Driver](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#redis-driver)

Answer (score 0):

**Enable Redis Session in CodeIgniter 3**
step 1:
install php_redis.dll or .so if using Windows/Linux according to:
Note: check right architecture (x64/486) and PHP version
check if thread safety enabled then download DLL file (architecture (x64/486)) Thread Safe else (architecture (x64/86)) non Thread 
https://pecl.php.net/package/redis

**For PHP version 7.1.4:**
Redis version 3.1.1
**For PHP version 8.0.3:**
Redis version 5.3.6
Rest of process is same codeigniter 3 has defult session driver 
session_redis_driver.php 
step 2:
Then download php _redis.dll then copy file & paste into PHP /ext/ folder
Then add in php.ini file 
extension=php_redis.dll 
session.save_path="tcp://127.0.0.1:6379" 
session.save_handler = "redis"

Then check if Redis is enabled in phpinfo() page some thing like this version may vary 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEaxb.png)

Step 3: add this setting in config.php file and comment file base session and add redis base sesson code
Follow this github repo for sample application
https://github.com/Aadichohan/CodeIgniter-Redis-Session

//$config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; 
//$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; 
//$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; 
//$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL; 
//$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE; 
//$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 7200; 
//$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; 
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; 
// $config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://localhost:6379'; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://localhost:6379?auth=123'; 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

**Redis Commands:** 
on redis-cli 
ping: to check if server is running result is pong 
set   
set name Ali 
get   
set name  
result: Ali 
flushall : to remove all cachedata 
keys *: to get all keys 
monitor: to monitor realtime cache addition

CONFIG SET requirepass passvalue: to set password 
CONFIG SET requirepass "":  to remove password

AUTH : to login into cli